# What happens when I transfer a Pokémon to the Professor?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I catch a Pokémon or when I select it in the menu I can select an option "TRANSFER"?

What happens when I transfer it to the Professor?

[image: TransferPokemon]

Comment: The transferred pokemon go to a "farm" where they "live happily ever after" and you can never, ever see them or visit them again.

Comment: @AdamDavis https://www.allmystery.de/i/t2ddae5_cute_meme.png

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Transfer the Pokémon to the Professor
>   You receive Candy in exchange for transferring a Pokémon. Be careful—you can’t get the Pokémon back after you’ve transferred it to the Professor.

cited from the [support page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049867-Viewing-a-Pok%C3%A9mon-s-Summary-)

You receive 1 candy per pokemon transferred, regardless of the pokemon's level of evolution or CP.  (Hat tip to @CreativiTimothy) for sharing this in the comments.

Comment: Alright, but what is candy for? Only found this funpost about it: :D https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4mx4d3/where_does_the_professor_get_the_pokemon_candy/  Google seems to spit not many results yet...

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Pokémon Candy is used for increasing the CP of your Pokémon. You need Candy and Stardust to increase the CP.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Haha thanks for sharing that post! Candy is used to power up and evolve your pokemon. The tip is never use your candy on pokemon with fairly low or average cp, since candy is still kinda hard to earn and save :P

Comment: @P1raten Yes, and candy can evolve pokemon.

Comment: What's the strategy then? Transfer low CP Pokemon that I have multiples of?

Comment: @EhevuTov exactly, you have Pokemon limit, so maybe you want to transfer the low CP Pokemon which you have more than 2.

Comment: @jay Wong why two and not one?

Comment: @EhevuTov hahaha sorry it's just my personal habit. I always want to collect at least two of one kind of Pokemon XD

Comment: @EhevuTov At least when starting you want to keep at least two because you probably want to evolve one.  Also, pokemon with the same name can have different attacks so you might want to keep a few with different attacks.  For instance I have a Rattata witih Tackle/Hyperfang and another with Quick Attack/Bodyslam.

Comment: Note that you only get 1 candy regardless of how evolved or how high CP the Pokemon is. Transferring a Pidgeot would only give 1 Pidgey candy, for example.

Answer (score 12):

Transfering to the Professor is a way of permanently removing a Pokemon from your inventory.

In exchange for a transfer, the Professor will give you some Candies, that can be used to power up and evolve a Pokemon. Note, however, that these Candies are limited to the "family" of Pokemon denoted.

Comment: I have only had single candies - but have only transfered "low grade" j

Answer (score 8):

Though implied in the answers so far, it might not be obvious that the purpose of this (in addition to candy) is because you have finite storage space for Pokemon; this allows you to free some up.